# Quant valuation of a credit card debt (or flexible loan)

Tags: fixed-income, credit-risk, valuation, debt

What would you say is the generally accepted quantitative method of valuing an individual credit card, or flexible loan? Is the method very changeable if that were a pool of such loans?

Suppose the characteristics of each loan were that they:

- Repaid a minimum amount of the loan balance each month, say 5%.
- Applied interest at some rate less than 5% per month, i.e. so balance always declines.
- Allowed flexible repayment upto the entire balance in any month.
- Might not repay (i.e. enter loan arrears)
- Officially default after being in arrears, and need to be recovered with some LGD parameter.

If anyone has academic paper links to this also appreciated.

Comment: Intuitively, I would say the valuation could be different if it were in a pool because its risk is diluted or kind of diversified away. Individually there is one input that is of paramount importance: "might not repay". Ball Park figure the valuation would be amount to recover times the probability of that happening.

Comment: I agree but also think the potentially perpetual nature of collecting (high) interest as opposed to the loan suddenly repaying (embedded partial callable) is important. If every loan (credit cp) was independent then I don't think the pool matters, you just have less variabiliy in the realised value of the whole as opposed to the individual loan, expected value is probably the same. However, I'm hoping someone has much more experience or knowledge than me...